# ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
UPDATE s SET sb = sb ||
                  ('{"filded": [{"@value": ' ||
                  sb@>>'{filded,0, @value}'::integer + 1 ||
                  '}],"lastFailure ": '[{"@t": "DateTime", "@value": "$1"}],ln": '[{"@type": "DateTime", "@value": "$1"}])::jsonb
WHERE sbi=$2
```

***this is my postgres sql query which i am trying to run in thi pgAdmin but it giving error***

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...d,0, @value}'::integer + 1 ||'}],"lastFailure ": '[{"@t": "D...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 116
```

Comment: Try not to build JSON values by string concatenation

Comment: You have single quotes in the middle of the string, and I have no idea what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Merely a guess on your mess:

```sql
UPDATE s
SET    sb = sb
         || ('{"filded":[{"@value":'
         || (sb #>> '{filded,0,@value}')::integer + 1
         || '}], "lastFailure":[{"@t":"DateTime", "@value":"$1"}], "ln":[{"@type":"DateTime", "@value":"$1"}]}')::jsonb
WHERE  sbi = $2;
```